# Is there any FREE ORM for .NET Compact Framework (Windows Mobile 6.1, SQLServerCE)?

Tags: orm

Looks like I found a good [commercial variant](http://www.llblgen.com/defaultgeneric.aspx), but I'm looking exactly for Free one. Does someone know some?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am currently looking for a free .net ORM for use on Windows CE.  So far I have found these commerical options:

- [DevXpress XPO](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/ORM/info.xml)
- [LLBLGenPro](http://www.llblgen.com/defaultgeneric.aspx)
- [EntitySpaces](http://www.entityspaces.net/portal/)

[NHibernate](https://www.hibernate.org) sadly is not an option because it uses features that are not available in the Compact Framework (e.g. reflection related functionality).

If using a SQL database as your underlying data store is not absolutely necessary then [Karvonite](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/karvonite) is worth consideration.  It is a free ([Ms-PL](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/karvonite/Project/License.aspx)) object persistence framework compatable with the .net Compact Framework.  Do you need to use SQL Server Compact or are you really just wanting an easy way to persist your domain?

I will update you if I find more options.

Answer (score 6):

How about the [OpenNETCF ORM](http://orm.codeplex.com)?  It's free, lightweight, and was built specifically for the Compact Framework, then ported to other platforms (as opposed to someone shoehorning a desktop ORM into the CF).

Comment: I don't longer need this. But anyway thank you. Maybe others will find this useful.

Answer (score 2):

I built [DapperLite](https://github.com/ryankirkman/DapperLite) to work on .NET Compact Framework and full .NET. It's basically a [Dapper](https://github.com/SamSaffron/dapper-dot-net) clone, so it's a [single file](https://github.com/ryankirkman/DapperLite/blob/master/DapperLite.NETCF35/SqlMapper.cs) under 200 lines you can drop into your project.

I had tried OpenNETCF.ORM but found it too opinionated. I love using [Dapper](https://github.com/SamSaffron/dapper-dot-net) in my desktop apps but unfortunately it doesn't work with .NET Compact Framework.

I also built a Micro-ORM layer over the top of DapperLite to make it a bit easier to use, which is essentially a clone of Dapper.Rainbow

Comment: I am just starting down the path of using this.  Where is the best place to ask questions as I stumble around?  Not that I'll have any.... ;-)

Comment: I see you're making comments on the GitHub project (https://github.com/ryankirkman/DapperLite) - that's the perfect place !