# Mapping objects on the compact framework

Tags: c#, compact-framework, sql-server-ce

I am developing a windows mobile application which runs on the .net compact framework and I am having trouble with my data access layer.

I have currently created the required entites (poco) which is working great as I can easily test the business logic by mocking the repository.

The problem I have is I am not sure how to map sql queries to the entities seeing as entity framework is not available in the compact framework.

Is this something I should try find an orm that is supported in the CF? I only have a handful of tables and could try mapping myself, but I don't want to get into the issue of pulling out a lot data that I don't need so would need some sort of lazy loading.

Have I taken the right approach or should I be looking elsewhere at things such as Datsets?

Comment: Suggest the CF ORM mapper by Chris Tacke http://orm.codeplex.com

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792978/designing-data-access-for-compact-framework-and-full-framework/

Comment: Do *not* use DataSets.  They are slow and bloated.  Nothing good ever came of them in a device application. An ORM (like ErikEJ suggests) is the route to go.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you look at [DapperLite](https://github.com/ryankirkman/DapperLite).  I have used [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) on a number of projects and it is a great light-weight and fast orm.  DapperLite looks like a promising conversion of Dapper for the compact framework.  The library is quite easy to use and there are plenty of usage examples.